# How to add in-line script functions in Jinja2 templates to run on page load of an extending HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a template HTML which contains a template  function. I am trying to get this function to execute onload trigger for pages that extends the template. Unfortunately this does not seem to work for me.

Clearly I am either not defining the function correctly, either in the template or the extending HTML file, or not placing or triggering them correctly.

I am just extracting the relevant parts of the scripts rather than entire HTML's, alongside the result of the page load. The labels in the cards in the resulting page will show my intent fro the script that did not materialize.

My template file code:

```
<!--signupandaccess/templates/base.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body class="body" onload = "removeCard(val)">
  <div class="toprow">
  </div>
  <div class="bottomrow">
    <main class="main">
       <div id="card1" class="card">
         {% block content_1 %}
         {% endblock %}
       </div>

       <!-- repeat 6x for 6 cards -->
            </main>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        {% block card_js %}
           $(function () {
            $("#abc").css("color", "red");
            });
        {% endblock %}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!--signupandaccess/templates/index.html-->
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content_1 %}Remove card1{% endblock %}

{% block content_2 %}Remove card2{% endblock %}

{% block content_3 %}Remove card3{% endblock %}

{% block content_4 %}KEEP Card4 & fill spaces vacated by removed cards{% endblock %}

{% block content_5 %}Remove card5{% endblock %}

{% block content_6 %}Remove card6{% endblock %}

{% block card_js %}
const cards = ["card1", "card2", "card3", "card4", "card5", "card6"];
cards.forEach(removeCard);
function removeCard(card_to_remove) {
    switch (card_to_remove) {
        case (card_to_remove !== "card4"):
            const element = document.getElementById(card_to_remove);
            element.remove();
            break;
        default:
    }
}
{% endblock %}
```

And lastly, the result I am seeing is the presence of the 5 cards that should have been removed by the function:

[image]

Please let me know if this makes clear of the issue and how could I fix this.